# Javascript using Window.history does not keep encoded URL parameter

Tags: javascript

I have a utf8 value as the value of a URL component. Assume this:

[http://example.com?username=شبنم](http://example.com?username=%D8%B4%D8%A8%D9%86%D9%85)

Now, the above pattern is not a proper one and is vulnerable to many problems. Therefore, I use `encodedURLComponent()` which converts `شبنم` to an encoded value. The problem is that when I manipulate them with `Window.History.replaceState()`, the `replaceState()` method decodes the value and put the utf8 string directly back into the URL, instead of observing the encoded value, it decodes them. How should I prevent it from decoding?